# Unable to decode a pycurl response

Tags: python, web-scraping, character-encoding, pycurl

I am trying to decode a pycurl html get request response but nothing works so far.
UTF-8 throws an error and the closest I got it was using iso-8859-1 encoding, but the response is intelligible.

This is my code:

```
import pycurl
import certifi
from io import BytesIO

## Create PycURL instance
c = pycurl.Curl()

## Define Options - Set URL we want to request
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://pycurl.io/')

## Setup buffer to recieve response
buffer = BytesIO()
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)

## Setup SSL certificates
c.setopt(c.CAINFO, certifi.where())

## Make Request
c.perform()

## Close Connection
c.close()

## Retrieve the content BytesIO & Decode
body = buffer.getvalue()
print(body.decode('iso-8859-1'))
```

This is part of the response using iso-8859-1 encoding.

```
EÑÛË Åð¦Öÿ¢ù|ÎB¥'Ñè:º#zD vìÚê0µiÐÃön×»<+LwW¯^ùå~²ài{Xi3Ñ,ësöAå
øDDþ9ÍÈåvÄ_u¾*¬(lg´(EÀ×
¬¸³mð#K¦\a»Ò
```

If I use UTF-8 the script throws an error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

What is wrong with my code? Apparently it is working for other people but not for me.

Comment: is the response gzipped still by chance? If not, maybe try `print(body.decode('windows-1252'))`

Comment: Yes, the response was gzipped. Thank you so much @JonSG now after decompressing it is a readable data.